# bash script that checks for open/closed ports and current ssh version

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to write a bash script that checks all ports if they are closed or open and if the current ssh version is good or needs an update.

below is the code i got figured out but i think it could be improved-

`$ ssh -p115 -vv exampel@xxx.com && /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release`

i already know that all the servers i am working with are reachable by port 115.

i am not sure if its even possible to get the current version without logging on to the server.

Comment: `ssh -p115 -vv exampel@xxx.com && /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release` is two commands issued *locally*.  If you need to check `ssh` version on the server, you should remove `&&` (since that's being interpreted by the local shell ). Without it, the `check-new-release` is parameter to `ssh`

Answer (score 2):

Use `nmap` (you may have to `sudo apt install nmap` first. Read `man nmap`. Reread `man nmap`, and do something like (MY system runs `sshd` on port 22):

```
sudo nmap -sV -p22 --version-all  localhost

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-02-07 09:22 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00010s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 7.2p2 Ubuntu 4ubuntu2.6 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.54 seconds
```

Comment: is it possible to add  the the comment with the version to it ?   like 
`&& /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release`
 without connecting to the server?

Answer (score 0):

> i am not sure if its even possible to get the current version without logging on to the server.

If you're running a infrastructure monitoring system like Nagios, there's probably a plugin or script for that, but let's assume you're stuck with barebones servers for whatever reason.

The common recommendation is to `nmap` your servers from another system, but it can get slow, and only covers the interfaces that you remember to probe. Since you'll have to login to the servers anyway, you might as well run a `netstat` to check for listening ports on *all* interfaces except loopback. This would be a strict superset of the ports that are actually accessible from any interface (`iptables` and other filtering rules may drop certain ports from this list), but it's **FAST** and doesn't suffer from false negatives.

Which leads to a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# USAGE: check_servers <host1> <host2> ...
for h in "$@"; do

  ssh -p115 -T "$h" <<'EOF'

echo -e "\n+++++ HOSTNAME: $(hostname) +++++"

echo ===== Checking for open ports =====
# Get all listening TCPv4/6 ports, then display non-loopback ones
netstat -tln | awk '$4 ~ /^[0-9:].*/ {print $4}' | grep -Ev '^(127\.|::1:|.*%lo)'

echo ===== Checking for new release =====
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release

EOF

done
```